# Help modeling this dome

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves, vertices, bmesh

I am very new to blender and still using 2.78, I have this idea in my head and but can't think of how to model a dome shape with a cross on top if that makes sense. I attached a sketch of how I want it to be, sorry if it is hard to understand. I don't care a lot about size or measurements.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I've tried this. It's made with bevels, mirror, extrusions, join and knife. I corrected the final extrusion as, as Lemon has pointed out, it looks like I inverted the cross.

[image]

Comment: I think you have inverted the extrusion of the cross

Comment: ooh ok, actually I thought it was flat, but anyway it's the same process  ;)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Have tried to do it in a minimalistic way.

First noticing that the shape is a double mirror (and that helped to make regular edge loop or knife cuts when needed):

[image]

From that, the mesh is the following:

[image]

The main point is the pinched extremity of the cross. The cross was extruded first, then the extremity has been merged to the edge it was extruded from. We so first obtain a triangle.

Edges are then marked as creases, and the creases (pink edges) are supported by edge loops as visible below.

[image]

[image]

**The base mesh and how to set the mirror modifiers:**

[image]

Above, from left to right:

- Add a plane
- Poke the face (menu 'face/poke face' in edit mode)
- Select all and bevel <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>
- Add edge loops at the diagonals <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> for each diagonal
- Keep a quarter
- Split the quarter in half

[image]

From the image above, the mirror modifiers setting (left and right):

- Add a simple (default mirror on X)
- Then add a second mirror on X and Y and base the mirroring on an empty placed at the origin (which has not moved so far, normally)
- Rotate the empty 45 degrees.

**Extruding and give the base shape**

[image]

From left to right:

- What we have done before
- The cross extruded
- The extremity down and merged with the base
- The global shape for the not extruded part

From that, add some loops, mark the crease, add some loop agin and cuts as described above.